# Plain text in italics

Tags: italic

I am writing a lemma in math which is the following using the italics parameter \textit but need to insert plain text that isn't italicized in the lemma. I can't just delete the \textit around my math lemma or else the lemma won't be in italics.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  if you're using a theorem package, you can insert a segment `\emph{...}` which will ordinarily set roman within an italic context.  you may have to adjust the intervening space a bit manually, depending on the particular wording, since the usual italic corrections don't work perfectly in this situation.  (can't give a more precise answer since you don't say what document class or packages you're using.)

Answer (score 4):

You could just stop the command, then restart it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\textit{Here is some itallic text,} some regular text, \textit{and more itallic text.}  

\end{document}
```

Would produce

[image]